# Can a AS3 class create instances of itself

Tags: actionscript-3

Would this work?

From the start of the game it creates a box sprite and this triggers a custom event.

If I use public static functions and some event listener such as this quasi-code:

```
 public static function tile()
 {
 if this hears statusbox.statuschanged 

and this triggers a static private function 
 } 

static private function 
create instances of tile 
with 
public function tile(id:uint,... )
```

Comment: You should try it, then you'll find if it's working on not. :) Normally it should work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason that a given class can't create instances of itself. You would just have to ensure that it didn't do so in any method called from its own constructor, or in any automatically instantiated class variables. Otherwise you would create a non-terminating loop! It's rather difficult to read your quasi code, but it sounds like you wouldn't be creating any inner references upon instantiation, so you'll probably be in the clear. To give some examples anyway:

Will work:

```
package {

    public class Tile {

        private var _innerTile:Tile;

        public function Tile() {

        }

        public function innerTile_create():Tile {
            _innerTile = new Tile();
            return _innerTile;
        }

    }

}
```

Won't work:

```
package {

    public class Tile {

        public function Tile() {
            var innerTile:Tile = new Tile();
        }

    }

}
```

Also won't work

```
package {

    public class Tile {

        private var _innerTile:Tile = new Tile();

        public function Tile() {

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: how do I call the public function start() that's in tile.as which starts the main part of the game though I suppose I can do  {
 if (stage) init();
   else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
  
 
  
 }
 private function init():void
 {
 removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);- what I didn't want to start it during initialisation?  Simple calls to start() give an error.